# How to make a table in an align environment?

Tags: tables, align, arrays

I wrote a few lines in an array environment to get the following. My problem is that (1) is appearing far below where I tag for it.

[image]

To add a tag I use the following macro (courtesy of some other user on this forum)

`\newcommand{\numberthis}[1]{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}\label{#1}}`

on the first line of the following code.

```
\[
    \begin{array}[]{c| c}
        \delta'\left( (s', \gamma),\e \right) = & (\delta(q,0), \alpha) \cup (\delta(q,1), \beta) \numberthis{joe}\\
        \hline
        \delta'\left( (q, \gamma), 0 \right) = & (\delta(q,0), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,1),\alpha) \\
        \delta'\left( (q, \gamma), 1 \right) = & (\delta(q,1), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,0), \beta) \\
        \hline
        \delta'\left( (q, \alpha), 1 \right) = & \emptyset \\
        \delta'\left( (q, \alpha), 0 \right) = & (\delta(q,1), \alpha) \\
        \hline
        \delta'\left( (q, \beta), 1 \right) = & \emptyset \\
        \delta'\left( (q, \beta), 0 \right) = & (\delta(q,1), \beta) \\
        \hline
        \delta'\left( (q, \beta), \e \right) = & \emptyset \\
    \end{array}
\]
```

Question: What should I do in order to be able to display the (1) where I intend for it to go? I have considered using an align environment instead of an array environment, but I cannot express my math as a nice-looking table doing so:

[image]

Comment: How would LaTeX know that this array is a list of equations rather than, say, a matrix? Please explain in more detail what the desired output is. Do you want the same vertical and horizontal line in a list of equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to change is to modify `\begin{array}[]{...}` to `\begin{array}[t]{...}`. And, move `\numberthis{joe}` outside the array.

A separate comment: If you plan to cross-reference this equation, do change `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` to `\refstepcounter{equation}`. Incidentally, the `\left` and `\right` directives don't actually enlarge the respective parentheses. Either change them to `\bigl` and `\bigr`, respectively, or get rid of them entirely.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}        % for "\tag" macro
\newcommand\e{\mathrm{e}}   % ?
\newcommand{\numberthis}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\numberthis{joe}
\begin{array}[t]{r|c}
   \delta'\bigl( (s',\gamma),\e \bigr)= & (\delta(q,0), \alpha) \cup (\delta(q,1), \beta)\\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\gamma), 0 \bigr) = & (\delta(q,0), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,1),\alpha)\\
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\gamma), 1 \bigr) = & (\delta(q,1), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,0), \beta)\\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\alpha), 1 \bigr) = & \emptyset \\
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\alpha), 0 \bigr) = & (\delta(q,1), \alpha) \\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\beta), 1 \bigr)  = & \emptyset \\
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\beta), 0 \bigr)  = & (\delta(q,1), \beta) \\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\beta), \e \bigr) = & \emptyset \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The vertical line doesn't seem necessary. IMNSHO, something like the following looks a lot less cluttered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand\e{\mathrm{e}} % ?
\newcommand{\numberthis}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\numberthis{joe}
\begin{array}[t]{@{} c @{{}={}} c @{}} % automatically insert "=" between the columns
   \delta'\bigl( (s',\gamma),\e \bigr)& (\delta(q,0), \alpha) \cup (\delta(q,1), \beta) \\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\gamma), 0 \bigr) & (\delta(q,0), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,1),\alpha) \\
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\gamma), 1 \bigr) & (\delta(q,1), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,0), \beta) \\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\alpha), 1 \bigr) & \emptyset \\
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\alpha), 0 \bigr) & (\delta(q,1), \alpha) \\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\beta), 1 \bigr)  & \emptyset \\
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\beta), 0 \bigr)  & (\delta(q,1), \beta) \\
   \hline
   \delta'\bigl( (q,\beta), \e \bigr) & \emptyset \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Second addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up question. To enable `\numberthis` to insert a right-aligned equation tag *anywhere* in the array, I recommend (a) switching from an `array` to an `align*` environment and (b) decluttering the material by replacing all `\hline` directives with a bit more whitespace. (Just how much more whitespace is subject to personal preferences; in the code below, I use `1ex`. Your preferences may differ from mine.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand\e{\mathrm{e}} % ?
\newcommand{\numberthis}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \delta'( (s',\gamma),\e )&= (\delta(q,0), \alpha) \cup (\delta(q,1), \beta) \\[1ex]
   \delta'( (q,\gamma), 0 ) &= (\delta(q,0), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,1),\alpha) \numberthis{joe}\\
   \delta'( (q,\gamma), 1 ) &= (\delta(q,1), \gamma) \cup (\delta(q,0), \beta) \\[1ex]
   \delta'( (q,\alpha), 1 ) &= \emptyset \\
   \delta'( (q,\alpha), 0 ) &= (\delta(q,1),\alpha)\\[1ex]
   \delta'( (q,\beta), 1 )  &= \emptyset \\
   \delta'( (q,\beta), 0 )  &= (\delta(q,1),\beta)\\[1ex]
   \delta'( (q,\beta), \e ) &= \emptyset \numberthis{bob}
\end{align*}
A cross-reference to equations \eqref{joe} and \eqref{bob}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do note that I replaced all `\left` and `\right` directives with `\bigl` and `\bigr`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if I wanted to insert a tag at any one of the 9 rows in the table? Also, what does t do? I have tried looking at manuals and primers for the array environment but have found no mention of this option.

Comment: @Muno - `[t]` is for "top"-alignment. My answer was based on the placement of the `\numberthis` directive in your sample code.

Comment: My mistake for not being clear in my question. Should I make a new question to address this point, then? Of being able to insert a tag at an arbitrary location?

Comment: @Muno - I'll post a second addendum to address your follow-up question.